# SQL query against one table showing counts of duplicate field values

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have a table with 5 fields. Two of the fields will have duplicate values that match. I think I need to use one or two JOINS to get the data results I want.

Fields: `Machine, Message, Date, Severity, ID`

The two fields that will have duplicates are Machine and Message.

EXAMPLE DATA:

```
MACHINE  |  MESSAGE
--------------------
MACHINE1 |  ERROR1
MACHINE2 |  ERROR1
MACHINE3 |  ERROR1
MACHINE2 |  ERROR2
MACHINE2 |  ERROR2
MACHINE3 |  ERROR3
MACHINE1 |  ERROR3
MACHINE1 |  ERROR1
```

I need the results to be like this:

```
MACHINE1, 2 - ERROR1, 1 - ERROR3

MACHINE2, 1 - ERROR1, 2 - ERROR2

MACHINE3, 1 - ERROR1, 1 - ERROR3
```

I've been trying to search for the answer to this but haven't found the answer. I believe I will need JOIN or two with a possible `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I don't understand what the expected results are. Are these 3 rows? What does "MACHINE1, 2" mean, for example?

Comment: Ok, I reformatted your message and now it makes sense... or I think :)

Comment: What SQL dialect is this? MySQL? SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #machineErrors (Machine nvarchar(20), Error nvarchar(20))

insert into #machineErrors values ('Machine1','Error1')
insert into #machineErrors values ('Machine2','Error1')
insert into #machineErrors values ('Machine3','Error1')
insert into #machineErrors values ('Machine2','Error2')
insert into #machineErrors values ('Machine2','Error2')
insert into #machineErrors values ('Machine3','Error3')
insert into #machineErrors values ('Machine1','Error3')
insert into #machineErrors values ('Machine1','Error1')

select  Machine, COUNT(*), [Error]
from    #machineErrors
group by Machine, [Error]
order by Machine, [Error]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the full question but seem like you are looking a pivoting features in SQL to aggregate your result based on different error(1,2,3) at machine.

Assume is MSSQL ?? So the query are based on the assumption there are 3 errors you would like to aggregate.

```
SELECT Machine, [Error1], [Error2], [Error3]
FROM
    MessageTable
Pivot
(
  COUNT(Machine)
  FOR ErrorColumn 
  IN ([Error1], [Error2], [Error3])
)
```